# MongoDB findById not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, monk

I'm using Monk and MongoDB to try and get a record by ID populate through the request params but it returns nothing.

I've tried lots of the suggestions on SO but nothing is working, does anyone have any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Here is my code:

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get('bugs');
  collection.findById(req.params.id, {}, function(e,docs){
      res.render('bug', { 'bug': docs });
  });
});
```

And I'm trying to access by going to `localhost:3000/bugs/recordidstring`

Thanks

Comment: How is it failing? Anything in error?

Comment: have you tried: .findOne({_id: req.params.id} ? If not, try it and see if it works. my first though is that "collection" isn't valid and outside of that, I'd assing req.params.id to a variable and then use that. var id = req.params.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was being an utter idiot and when I was connecting to the DB I was connecting to the wrong one!

Sorry guys, my bad!